# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.(WebResponse)

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows phone 8.1 application where i am receiving data from an IP Camera..

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "12345");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
using (var response = await req.GetResponseAsync())
{
    ///Some Logic
}
```

and i am getting this `HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.` error in response

There is nothing wrong with the connection, the same logic i tested for a Windows Store app and it's working perfectly.

I checked all the required capabilities in the manifest.

And i deleted the project Cache from the below location:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache`

And re-build the cache using `devenv.exe /setup`

But no luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your xaml I had a space between  "  {

see

FontWeight=" {Binding Path=SatisfactionSurveyStyles.SelectedListBoxItemFontWeight, Source={StaticResource LocalizationFiles}}"

and it crashed the whole app everytime I made any service call on that page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550709/windows-phone-8-service-call-causes-error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from/33550710#33550710